# ANTLR: too greedy rule

Tags: antlr, antlr4

It looks like I have a problem understanding a too greedy rule match. I'm trying to lex a `.g4` file for syntax coloring. Here is a minimum (simplified) extract for making this problem reproducible:

```
lexer grammar ANTLRv4Lexer;

Range
    : '['  RangeChar+  ']'
    ;

fragment EscapedChar
    : '\\' ~[u]
    | '\\u' EscapedCharHex EscapedCharHex EscapedCharHex EscapedCharHex
    ;

fragment EscapedCharHex
    : [0-9A-Fa-f]
    ;

fragment RangeChar
    : ~']'
    | EscapedChar
    ;

Punctuation
    : [:;()+\->*[\]~|]
    ;

Identifier
    : [a-zA-Z0-9]+
    ;

Whitespace
    : [ \t]+
      -> skip
    ;

Newline
    : ( '\r' '\n'?
      | '\n'
      )
      -> skip
    ;

LineComment
    : '//' ~[\r\n]*
    ;
```

The (incomplete) test file is following:

```
   : (~ [\]\\] | EscAny)+ -> more
   ;

   // ------

fragment Id
   : NameStartChar NameChar*
   ;


String2Part
    : ( ~['\\]
      | EscapeSequence
      )+
    ;
```

I don't understand why it matches `Range` so greedy:

```
[@0,3:3=':',<Punctuation>,1:3]
[@1,5:5='(',<Punctuation>,1:5]
[@2,6:6='~',<Punctuation>,1:6]
[@3,8:135='[\]\\] | EscAny)+ -> more\r\n   ;\r\n\r\n   // ------\r\n\r\nfragment Id\r\n   : NameStartChar NameChar*\r\n   ;\r\n\r\n\r\nString2Part\r\n\t: ( ~['\\]',<Range>,1:8]
[@4,141:141='|',<Punctuation>,13:3]
[@5,143:156='EscapeSequence',<Identifier>,13:5]
[@6,162:162=')',<Punctuation>,14:3]
[@7,163:163='+',<Punctuation>,14:4]
[@8,167:167=';',<Punctuation>,15:1]
[@9,170:169='<EOF>',<EOF>,16:0]
```

I understand why in the first line it matches `[`, `\]` and `\\`, but why it obviously treats `]` as `RangeChar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lexer matches the first `\` in `\\]` using the `~']'` alternative and then matches the remaining `\]` as an `EscapedChar`. The reason it does this is that this interpretation leads to a longer match than the one where `\\` is the `EscapedChar` and `]` is the end of the range and when there are multiple valid ways to match a lexer rule, ANTLR always chooses the longest one (except when `*?` is involved).

To fix this, you should change `RangeChar`, so that backslashes are only allowed as part of escape sequences, i.e. replace `~']'` with `~[\]\\]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed that it would skip the `~']'` in case of a backslash because the `EscapedChar` match would be longer.

Comment: @ThomasS. Yeah, but the principle of maximum munch applies to the lexer rule, not to fragments. That is, it goes with the path that produces the longest possible match for `Range`, not `RangeChar`.